# Compute pairwise Pearson's R in parallel with tasks separated by pairs of columns of an array

Tags: python, namespaces

This code was an answer to my own [question on SO](//stackoverflow.com/questions/68411538), however I am looking at the line `global X` and wondering if there is a better way to do this. I try to minimize the amount of global declarations in my code in order to avoid namespace collisions. I'm considering changing this code to use [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), but I would like some feedback on the code below 'as is'.

The purpose of this code is to compute in parallel the [Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) on all pairs of random variables. The columns of NumPy array `X` index the variables, and the rows index the sample.

$$r_{x,y} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i- \bar{x})(y_i- \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i- \bar{x})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i- \bar{y})^2}}$$

This is actual code that should run on your machine (ex. `python 3.6`).

```py
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from multiprocessing import Pool

X = np.random.random(100000*10).reshape((100000, 10))

def function(cols):
    result = X[:, cols]
    x,y = result[:,0], result[:,1]
    result = pearsonr(x,y)
    return result

def init():
    global X 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(initializer=init, processes=4) as P:
        print(P.map(function, combinations(range(X.shape[1]), 2)))
```

In addition to considering `global X`, any constructive feedback and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of the code. What problem does it solve? Perhaps taking a look at the [help/on-topic] will help in determining whether you posted your question in the right place, especially the part talking about example code might be relevant.

Comment: "toy examples", sadly, are explicitly off-topic for CodeReview. If you show this code in its real context we are more likely able to help you.

Comment: @Reinderien Toy examples being off-topic surprises me. I expect they should have clearer and simpler scope and behaviour, and consequently easier to explain and understand. I will have to think on whether to edit or delete this question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: To a first approximation, `global` is never needed in Python (the legitimate exceptions are truly rare). Even more strongly, one can say the `global` will never help with any kinds of shared-memory or parallelism problems, because it doesn't address the real issue — namely, what happens when two processes/threads operate on the same data and the same time.

Comment: The applied edits do not address the close reason.  Note that the close reason is essentially saying that there isn't enough code to review.  So to address it, you would need to add more code.  Of course, since there is an answer, you can't do that.  Rather than throwing it into the Reopen queue, a better approach would be to discuss it on meta.

Comment: @mdfst13 For future questions, it would be useful to know precisely how much code is required.

Comment: Sure, which is also better asked on meta if the links in the close reason are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to write anything to `X` (which it seems you are not doing), and just going to read from it, you should be good to just have all processes access the same variable without some locking mechanism.

Now, `global` is not necesarily the way to go. Here is different approach:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MyCalculator:

    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X

    def function(self, cols):
        result = self.X[:, cols]
        x,y = result[:,0], result[:,1]
        result = pearsonr(x,y)
        return result


def main():
    X = np.random.random(100000*10).reshape((100000, 10))
    myCalculator = MyCalculator(X)
    with Pool(processes=4) as P:
        print(P.map(myCalculator.function, 
                    combinations(range(X.shape[1]), 2)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, good work on inferring that I am interested in the read-only cases.

Comment: Tried to run the code in this answer and got a traceback: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.<lambda>'`.

Comment: My bad, I'll update the approach. Nested function cannot be pickeld

Comment: I have found that the [Pathos library](https://pathos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pathos.html) uses dill rather than pickle for serialization. Dill can serialize nested functions.